# cell array to numeric array for plotting

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell-array, textscan

I have a cell array containing historic gold price data and a cell array with the associated dates. I want to plot dates against prices for simple analysis but I am having difficulty converting the cell array of prices into a doubles.

My code is:

```
figure
plot(Date,USDAM,'b')
title('{\bf US Gold Daily Market Price, 2010 to 2015}')
datetick
axis tight
```

When I try to convert the gold prices (`USDAM`) into a double using `cell2mat(USDAM)`, it throws the following error:

> Error using cat
>   Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
>
> Error in cell2mat (line 83)
>               m{n} = cat(1,c{:,n});

I use the following code to import the data:

```
filename = 'goldPriceData.csv';
delimiter = ',';
startRow = 2;
endRow = 759;
formatSpec = '%s%s%*s%*s%*s%*s%*s%[^\n\r]';

fileID = fopen(filename,'r');


dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, endRow-startRow+1, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'EmptyValue' ,NaN,'HeaderLines', startRow-1, 'ReturnOnError', false);

fclose(fileID);

Date = dataArray{:, 1};
USDAM = dataArray{:, 2};
```

Comment: Post a minimal example with an input variable that reproduces the problem

Comment: are your dimensions correct? What of type are the elements in the cell?

Comment: Dates is of class cell of 758x1  which contains '2014-12-31'

Comment: USD is also a cell array of 758x1 which contains gold prices such as '1199.25'

Comment: when i use str2double(USDAM) it returns a 758x1 matrix of class double with values like '1.199250000000000e+03' as opposed to the correct price of 1199.25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your problem, `cell2mat` is the wrong function.  Consider the cell array of strings:

```
>> S = {'1.2';'3.14159';'2.718'}
S = 
    '1.2'
    '3.14159'
    '2.718'
>> cell2mat(S)
Error using cat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
Error in cell2mat (line 83)
            m{n} = cat(1,c{:,n});
```

That's because each row of the output needs to have the same number of columns, the strings are of different length.  You can use `strvcat(S)` to get a rectangular matrix padded with spaces, but that isn't what you want.  You want numeric data.

```
>> str2double(S)
ans =
    1.2000
    3.1416
    2.7180
```

Just because it puts a number in scientific notation, doesn't mean it's not the same number.  That is, `1.199250000000000e+03` *is* `1199.25`.  To get the tick labels looking the way you want them, set `YTickLabel` property of the axis with formatted strings, the ones in `USD`.

Regarding your dates, you'll need numeric data to plot on each axis so convert the dates with `datenum`.

```
>> dateVals = datenum({'2014-12-30', '2014-12-31'})
dateVals =
      735963
      735964
```

Then to get the dates displayed on the x axis correctly, set the `XTickLabel` properties of the axis to get it looking how you want it (using the strings in `Dates`).  Note that for setting the tick labels, you must ensure that you have the correct (same) number of ticks as labels that you indent to have.  But that is a different question, I think.

Comment: If I now want to forecast future price data using estimate regression how would I do this and show it on the same figure?

Comment: Mdl = regARIMA('ARLags',1,'MALags',1);

Comment: fit = estimate(Mdl,USDAM);

Comment: [Yf,YMSE,U] = forecast(fit,100,'Y0',USDAM);

Comment: Plot with `hold on`.  Please ask a new question for more exact advice.